# A question on the changing of "tel" to "si" when the corresponding noun is modified by another adjective

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs, adverbes, noms, adjectifs-indefinis

My understanding of ***tel*** is that it can act as an indefinite adjective as well as a qualifying adjective*.

Example of *tel* acting as an indefinite adjective:

- *Une telle faiblesse est en fait votre force.* = Such a weakness is actually your strength.

Example of *tel* acting as a qualifying adjective:

- *Elle est un tel gâchis.*  = She is such a mess.

My question is the following: According to *cliffsnotes* **:

> when another adjective is being used to describe the same noun *tel* is acting on, *tel* changes to *si*.

Now I just need some clarification on the matter. By "another adjective" do they mean any BANGS adjective or do they mean all qualifying adjectives? Secondly, does it just apply to when *tel* is acting as a qualifying adjective or does it also apply to when *tel* is acting as an indefinite adjective too?

So to be as explicit as possible, which of the following are true?

> 1) When *tel* is acting as an indefinite adjective and a BANGS adjective acts on the same noun *tel* is acting on, *tel* changes to *si*.
>
> 2) When *tel* is acting as an indefinite adjective and a qualifying adjective acts on the same noun *tel* is acting on, *tel* changes to *si*.
>
> 3) When *tel* is acting as qualifying adjective and a BANGS adjective acts on the same noun *tel* is acting on, *tel* changes to *si*.
>
> 4) When *tel* is acting as qualifying adjective and a qualifying adjective acts on the same noun *tel* is acting on, *tel* changes to *si*.

*Qualifying adjective is what normally comes to mind when we think of the word adjective e.g. blue, big, scary etc.

** https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-ii/french-ii-indefinites-passive-voice/indefinite-adjectives

Comment: *Elle est un tel gâchis* doesn't sound French. We might say *c'est un tel gâchis* or *son attitude est un tel gâchis*

Answer (score 4):

Neither the location of the adjective (before or after the noun) or the indefinite/qualifying status of *tel* seem to affect the rule.

- *Une telle faiblesse est en fait votre force.*
- *Une <s>telle grande</s> faiblesse est en fait votre force.*
- *Une **si** grande faiblesse est en fait votre force.*
- *Une <s>telle faiblesse inattendue</s> est en fait votre force.*
- *Une faiblesse **si** inattendue est en fait votre force.*

---

- *Je n'ai jamais vu un tel orage !*
- *Je n'ai jamais vu un <s>tel violent orage</s> !*
- *Je n'ai jamais vu un **si** violent orage.* (*...un orage si violent*)
- *Je n'ai jamais vu un <s>tel orage matinal</s> !*
- *Je n'ai jamais vu un orage **si** matinal.*

---

- *C'est un tel gâchis !*
- *C'est un <s>tel incroyable gâchis</s> !*
- *C'est un si incroyable gâchis !* (*...un gâchis si incroyable*)

Comment: How does one say "such big weaknesses are actually your strengths"? Is it "si grandes faiblesses sont en fait votre forces"?

Comment: That would be *De si grandes faiblesses sont en fait votre force*.

Comment: So the sentence "such evil feelings are unhealthy for a person" is equal to "de si malveillantes sentiments sont malsains pour une personne" ?

Comment: Yes, outside the gender issue: *de si malveillants sentiments sont...*